# Windows 10 - How can I show the disk space usage amount/bar in My PC with large icons?

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, user-interface

"`This PC`" will show the disk space usage amount and/or bar for each drive in certain views, like the default view and detail view. Is there a way to display the bar and/or amount with large icons?

I've found lots of posts on how to restore either the bar and/or the usage amount if it goes away, but every solution I have found involves using the "normal" icon size, and I would like to do it with large icons.

I tried playing with the registry keys mentioned in this question [Disk Usage Bar not showing in Windows Server 2008](https://superuser.com/questions/1027801/disk-usage-bar-not-showing-in-windows-server-2008) but I could only get it to change the appearance of the views that were already showing this information, rather than adding it to a view that wasn't.

> [image: Defauilt]
>
> Default

> [image: Details]
>
> Details

> [image: Large Icons]
>
> Large Icons

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't think there's a way to do this. The used/free space bar chart is not an icon overlay, but a separate piece of information, and as such, can only be shown in views that support multiple rows/columns.

All you can really do in vanilla Windows is use `Group By...` to get an idea of roughly how full the drives are by which bucket they're put into.

While it's certainly possible to make a shell extension that does what you want, I was unable to find any that already exist online. If you're willing to try it yourself, or pay a developer to make one, you might want to check out [this CodeProject article on Shell Icon Overlay Handlers](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/545781/net-shell-extensions-shell-icon-overlay-handlers).